# Is there a way to make CSS tags take user input

Tags: html, css

### Hello

So I am trying to code a CSS library for fun, and was wondering something.

I've been experimenting with classes, similar to bootstrap, and was wondering if I could use css to write a function. For example:

To write a gradient red to blue from left, you use *`.b-grd-from-left-red-blue`*. Now there are only so many colors programmed in, so i was wondering is there a way so that the user can specify *`.b-grd-from-(direction)-(color1)-(color2)`*. Is that possible, and if so, how would you reccomend I go about it.

In the library, my friend, who is also working on the project wrote a python automator to match every color and every direction, but I was wondering if it was possible to shorten the entire 5800 or so lines of code into a couple.

Also, Is this possible in pure css, or would it require js

### The colors

- white
- lightgrey -> #eaeaea
- silver
- grey
- darkgrey ->#555555
- black
- blue
- lightblue
- softblue -> #0099ff
- darkblue
- teal
- green
- lightgreen
- yellow
- softyellow -> #eeee88
- red
- orange
- pink
- lightpink
- purple
- brown
- lightbrown->#bf7b77

Comment: This seems similar to https://tailwindcss.com/ approach to writing CSS (utility first CSS). You can inspect how they do it - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops#app

Comment: @JureC. Thanks I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot create functions or variables unless you were using a preprocessor such as Sass. Although Sass is great I think you would be better of using JavaScript for something like this.

Check out [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) if you haven't already.

Comment: but can't you use `:root{--my-var: blue}` and then call it using `background-color: var(--my-var);` ?